# Letter spacing incorrect for one word only

Tags: html, css, layout, letter-spacing

When using `letter-spacing` we get the expected result, except for one part of the text and only on mobile (android and iphone).

This is the desired result on desktop:

[image]

And this is how it looks on mobile; notice the "finest"

[image]

There is nothing special in the code:

```
<div>
  <p>It's a way of life</p>
  <p>Ibiza's finest villas</p>
</div>
```

And the `CSS` on the div:

```
font-family: 'KremlinW08-ExpandedDemi';
font-style: italic;
letter-spacing: 9.0pt;
```

Any suggestions on how to solve it and what might be causing it?

Comment: Can you please provide font-family?

Comment: @RevtiShah I have updated the css.

Comment: Its paid font. Can you please put your code in the snippet?

Comment: try `font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;` (or `none`) (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures)

Comment: Can you provide the link to the website?

Comment: @HugoDelsing  I have checked. It is absolutely working fine.

Comment: @RevtiShah I guess I photoshopped the issue then just so I could ask a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a behaviour due to the ligatures of this font between `f` and `i` (and probably also between other characters)

Try applying  `font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;`

Reference on [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures)